# .Net equivalent of message driven beans

Tags: java, .net, message-driven-bean

Is there an equivalent of Java Message Driven Beans for .Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is called a Message Queue.

The documentation for the namespace is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xes6983c.aspx , and you can read a tutorial at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/MessageQueue.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use MessageQueues.  The link includes a tutorial about the bottom.

[MessageQueue from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.aspx)